# Gazebo doesn't publish /clock

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-11

```
gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 
        'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '-r' '-sim-time'],
    output='screen')        

# ros2_node = ExecuteProcess(
#         cmd=['ros2', 'param', 'set', '/gazebo', 'use_sim_time', use_sim_time],
#         output='screen')

# Replaced by a single call below
# start_gazebo_server_cmd = ExecuteProcess(
#     cmd=['gzserver', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so', world, '-r' '-sim-time'],
#     cwd=[def_launch_dir], output='screen')
```

If comments are switched, i.e. if I start client and server separately, /clock is published, if not, it is not. So my question is, how to use the first code snippet:

```
gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 
        'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '-r' '-sim-time'],
    output='screen')
```

so it publishes /clock. I suspect, there is some kind of parameter to pass, but not sure.

I use Galactic and Gazebo Classic.

Also, unfortunately, in a second (commented out) code, something is missing: Gazebo doesn't show robot and RViz says there is no transformation to world. But /clock is published :)

Comment: So... any idea how to make

gazebo_node = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', world, '-s', 
        'libgazebo_ros_factory.so', '-r' '-sim-time'],
    output='screen')
publish /clock?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it looks like the answer is "you can not". You have to start Gazebo client and server separately.

The working project can be downloaded at [robotics.snowcron.com](https://robotics.snowcron.com)